# Disposing different types of Objects

Tags: c#, c#-4.0

I used to dispose elements of type :

```
SqlConnection
SqlDataAdapter
DataSet etc.
```

But i am not sure whether it is needed to dispose for objects of type:

```
    string[] str = ;
    ArrayList etc.

Object of some class
```

If it is needed..Please tell me if it is ok just to dispose it this way

```
If(str != null)
{
  str = null;
}
```

Please suggest me if any better way is there to address this.

Comment: If it doesn't implement `IDisposable`, you don't need to dispose it.

Comment: I would recommend you to have a look at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms973837.aspx since it gives a quite good view of the garbage collection implemantation i .NET.

Comment: @Steven is correct, but not only you don't *need* to dispose such object, you **can't** do that since it has no `Dispose()` method.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, only objects implementing the [`IDisposable`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.idisposable.aspx) interface need to be deterministacally disposed of. Ideally you should wrap them in [`using statement`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yh598w02.aspx) and not call the `.Dispose` method manually:

```
using (var conn = new SqlConnection(ConnectionString))
using (var cmd = conn.CreateCommand())
{
    conn.Open();
    cmd.CommandText = "SELECT foo FROM bar";
    using (var reader = cmd.ExecuteCommand())
    {
        while (reader.Read())
        {
            // TODO: consume your resultset
        }
    }
}
```

or streams:

```
using (var stream = new MemoryStream())
{
    ...
}
```

or files:

```
using (var file = File.OpenRead())
{
    ...
}
```

or readers:

```
using (var reader = XmlReader.Create("foo.xml"))
{
    ...
}
```

The `IDisposable` pattern is used in .NET when an object is holding references to unmanaged objects that need to be disposed and the CLRT cannot track and dispose those unmanaged resources automatically. In this case it is up to the developer to dispose them deterministically as soon as he has finished using them (by wrapping them in `using statements` as shown previously). For all other objects that do not implement the IDisposable interface you should leave the memory menagement to the CLR and the Grbage Collector which will track them and automatically release the memory they are holding when no more references are pointing to them. You, as a developer should not worry about it.

So here's the rule of thumb:

> When you instantiate some variable, if this variable implements IDisposable then wrap it in a using statement, if not, then leave it to the Garbage Collector.

Comment: When it is an Object of class...Do we need to dispose it after work is done?

Comment: No, you don't need. The garbage collector will take care of it.

Comment: Actually when trying to use `using` block on objects that do not implement `IDisposable` you get compilation error: *type used in a using statement must be implicitly convertible to 'System.IDisposable'*

Answer (score 1):

#### Setting to `null`

What you are doing with `str` is not disposing it; you are simply "losing a reference to it" by assigning a `null` value. This will presumably leave the object unused by your code and let the GC collect its memory sooner. Obviously, it's only meaningful only for fields inside long-lived objects because local variables will leave their values unused as soon as the method that uses them returns.

An example: if you have an object with a field containing an array of strings, and you are sure that you won't need to access this array again for the lifetime of the object, you can set this array to `null` so that the GC can reclaim the memory the array (and its items) uses before the object itself is collected.

#### Disposing

"Proper" disposing is only performed on objects that implement [`IDisposable`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.idisposable.aspx), which means objects that allocate non-memory resources such as operating system handles.

Comment: So by this did you mean..if i dont need a string[] or an object of some class..I should be assigning it to null??

Comment: @RatanSharma: Only if you won't need it again, and only if the class itself is long-lived (otherwise as soon as it is collected its fields will also be collected). This is typically rare, most of the time you don't need to do it.